# How to construct Ruby regex that matches up to first example of a multi character pattern?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a multiline fragment of ruby code from which I need to extract the arguments to a particular method, method `foo` in this example:

```
code = "qux = define {\n  foo an arbitrary statement\n    that could go on for \n    several lines\n  bar 42\n  baz\43\n}"
```

From this I would like to extract `an arbitrary statement\n   that could go on for \n   several lines`. For this purpose I'd like to capture everything between `foo` and the first instance of `/^\s{2}\w+/`, marking the start of the next method and its argument.

Among my failures to do this (within `code.match(<example regex here>)[1]`) are:

```
/foo(.*)\s{2}\w+/m
/^\s+foo(.*)^\s{2}\w+/m
/\n\s+foo(.*)\n\s{2}\w+/m
/\n\s+foo(.*)\n\s{2}\w+?/m
```

Et cetera. None seem to return the "statement" pattern I'm looking for. Lazy/greedy operators have some effect, but never eliminate all of the string after the target `foo(.*)` pattern.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your logic is erroneous. the word `that` follows four spaces which matches `/\s{2}\w+/`.

Comment: How should one know that the example statement should end at ´bar 42´? You probably need a parser for this.

Comment: The pattern that ends the selection is "newline, then 2 spaces, then 1 or more word characters". My attempt to encode that is `/^\s{2}\w+/`. The problem is that I can't get a selection that _ends_ before that pattern.

Comment: Your example code fragment is not valid Ruby code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r = /
    (?<=     # begin a positive lookbehind
      \b     # match a (zero-width) word break
      foo    # match string
      [ ]    # match a space
    )        # close positive lookbehind
    .*?      # match zero or more chars, non-greedily
    (?=      # begin a positive lookahead
      \n     # match newline char
      [ ]{2} # match two spaces
      \w     # match a word char
    )        # close positive lookahead
    /xm      # free-spacing and multiline modes

code[r]
  #=> "an arbitrary statement\n    that could go on for \n    several lines"
```

The conventional expression for the regular expression is as follows.

```
/(?<=\bfoo ).*?(?=\n  \w)/m
```

Notice that in free-spacing mode I've matched spaces with with a character class containing one space (`[ ]`). Had I used spaces, as I did in the regex immediately above, they would have been removed because I was using *free-spacing* mode to define the regex, which disregards spaces.

It's important that the expression that captures the string that is returned be *non-greedy* (`.*?` rather than `.*`). If it were greedy (`.*`) we would obtain an erroneous result, as illustrated by the following example:

```
str = "foo oh my\n  a\n  b\n  c"
str[r]
  #=> "oh my"
str[/(?<=\bfoo ).*(?=\n  \w)/m]
  #=> "oh my\n  a\n  b"
```

In the greedy case, `.*` gobbles up as much as in can until it comes to the last possible match of the positive lookahead `(?=\n  \w)`, namely `"\n  c"`.

The *word break* (`\b`) is to ensure that we do not match, for example, `"snafoo"`. It requires that `"foo"` be preceded by a non-word character or be the first character of the string.

Another way to write the regex is as follows.

```
code[/\bfoo \K.*?(?=\n  \w)/m]
  #=> "an arbitrary statement\n    that could go on for \n    several lines"
```

`\K` can be read, "discard everything matched so far when returning the matched string". That is, the part before `\K` must be matched; it just isn't used in forming the matched string that is returned.

A final way to write the regex is to use a capture group.

```
code[/\bfoo (.*?)\n  \w/m, 1]
  #=> "an arbitrary statement\n    that could go on for \n    several lines"
```

The string of interest is captured in capture group `1`, and then is returned in [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)'s optional second argument.

Lastly, note that `\w` toward the end has the same effect as `\w+`.